# How to open the View from command in eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to open a view using the code with the help of HandlerUtil, how can I do it in Eclipse RCP ?

I've tried with `PlatformUI`.

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("MyView");
```

but I need to perform it with `HandlerUtil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getActiveWorkbenchWindow` in `HandlerUtil`:

```java
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler {
  @Override
  public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    IWorkbenchPage workbenchPage = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage();

    workbenchPage.showView("MyView");
  }
}
```